# Web designer equivalent in Android and iOS worlds?

Tags: design, android, ios, user-experience, ui

When web came, for years designers would create stunning designs in Photoshop, and developers would try to translate those designs to HTML/CSS/JS. This had many problems with itself. Lack of concurrent engineering would trigger many back-and-forth trips between design and development. Developers didn't have keen eye to translate design EXACTLY as requested. Design elements like typography, color, alignments and distances would usually differ from the original image file.

Until after a huge amount of expenses excreted upon companies, a new generation of skilled people emerge. People who had the taste of what looks beautiful, and the logic of how turn that beautiful thing into native code of the given environment, which for browser was HTML/CSS/JS.

In our company, we face the exactly same problem in the realm of Android and iOS.

We develop many applications, and the more we develop, the less we're successful in the area of UI/UX. Yeah we're familiar with mocking, with Adobe XD, with wire-framing, and a bunch of other methods and procedures.

Yet none of them are efficient. And the exact same problems of web exists in devices.

My question is this: Do we have something equivalent that we're not aware of? Is there a new skill that encompasses both design and develop in Android? Developing layout XML files and importing drawables. And equivalent people who can work natively in XCode, creating storyboards, etc?

Comment: Dear users who voted for closing. I'm an experienced user of StackExchange ecosystem, and I've checked help again to make sure that this question is on-topic. It's about software engineering, it's absolutely objective, it's not local, rather it's global and applies to all companies making apps, and it's also not too broad to answer. We're all here to help each other and I DO HAVE this question. Could you please clarify your reasons for voting?

Comment: If you have an issue with the scope, please start a discussion on Meta. I think this question is off topic but can't quite put my finger on it. While your question is about software engineering in a very wide sense, it's not about a concrete software engineering problem – that doesn't mean it's automatically off topic, but makes it more difficult to ask a good question. The part about “a job title that we should use to hire skilled people” is clearly off topic as per my understanding.

Comment: @amon, let's put it this way. If we ask a question about scrum method, and specifically about a role like scrum master the question won't be closed. Because it's already given a name. If we ask a question about web designers it won't be closed, because it's been given a name. My question is about a concept that is apparently objective, yet still has no name. The section `a job title ...` is for clarification. I'll remove it if that's what makes it off-topic.

Comment: There's nothing in any way objective about job titles, but that's not the real problem with your question.  Hiring and finding qualified people are subjects that are categorically off-topic here.  See also [On the Troubles with Naming and Terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology/6583).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, what is the definition of objectivity? Anything that is outside of our brain, and will live even if we die. I've not asked `should I love a rabbit or not`? I've asked about a fusion of designers and developers in the realm of device development, that has happened beforehand in the realm of browsers. Am I wrong? I deleted that part of hiring. You are all truly disappointing. I explained that it's only there for clarification so that people understand better my meaning. But you only point to that part again. I deleted that part.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, also in the link you posted, please see [this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6584/31418). This answer has more votes, which means even democratically people vote for objectivity (though it's not votable by nature).

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: That's not what "objective" means.  But as I already stated, that's not the real problem with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you describe is not so much that the developer has no eye for design, but the designer has no appreciation for the restrictions of the medium.

In the early days of the web, you were severely limited in what you could do. Fonts for example were often simply impossible to use. Instead you would have to resort to an image. which then wouldn't flow well with various resolutions etc.

It wasn't until designers started to appreciate that their designs had to work with multiple browsers, multiple screen resolutions, window sizes, aspect ratios etc etc that the design process started to flow more smoothly.

With mobile devices we have similar problems. With screen size, performance of visual effects, lock screens, switching apps, notifications, widgets, the status bar etc etc.

You can't just draw a pretty layout in Photoshop and expect it to look good or even the same on even a small selection of test devices.

So, hire a designer that has designed pretty apps before, hire a developer who has made pretty apps before and don't be tempted to judge their designs.